# The best overloaded method match for "" has some invalid arguments works with same query on different table

Tags: c#, sql

I have added a new table in my database, and updated my MSDModel.

Now i want to show the new values from that table to my application with a query that i already have.

***What i have now:***

[image: Database table 1]

**The code:**

```
context.Load(context.GetScannerStatusHistoryQuery(selectedDetector.DetectorID, datePickerFrom.SelectedDate.Value, datePickerTo.SelectedDate.Value), TemperatureHistoryLoaded2, null);
```

**And then the query:**

```
[Query]
public IQueryable<ScannerStatusHistory> GetScannerStatusHistory(int detectorID, DateTimeOffset dateFrom, DateTimeOffset dateTo)
{
    return ObjectContext.ScannerStatusHistories.Where(t => t.DetectorID == detectorID && t.TimeStamp >= dateFrom && t.TimeStamp <= dateTo);
}
```

Now the query etc. should be working. However, the code is giving the error:

> The best overloaded match for "" has some invalid arguments

***What i had and was working:***

[image: Database table 2]

**The Code:**

```
context.Load(context.GetTemperatureHistoryQuery(selectedDetector.DetectorID, datePickerFrom.SelectedDate.Value, datePickerTo.SelectedDate.Value), TemperatureHistoryLoaded2, null);
```

**And then the query:**

```
[Query]
public IQueryable<TemperatureHistory> GetTemperatureHistory(int detectorID, DateTimeOffset dateFrom, DateTimeOffset dateTo)
{
    return ObjectContext.TemperatureHistories.Where(t => t.DetectorID == detectorID && t.DateTime >= dateFrom && t.DateTime <= dateTo);
}
```

Why was it working with my old table, but not with my new table?
Everything is the same, however it is giving me this error.

Comment: Why exactly did you switch from `DateTime` to `TimeStamp`?

Comment: The new table receives different data. The person who made it added the column TimeStamp. It does the same, only the name is different.

Comment: Just asking... Cause they got a different syntax while your database still uses `DateTime` and MSSQL reacts "special" to Timestamp values.  MySQL does not accept `TimeStamp` values that include a zero in the day or month column or values that are not a valid date.

Comment: The **TemperatureHistory DateTime** contains values like this: **2016-02-03 15:00:00.0000000 +00:00** And the  **ScannerStatusHistory TimeStamp** contains values like this: **2017-01-06 14:40:40.0000000 +01:00**

Comment: Could you try using DateTime instead?

Comment: @Cataklysim It's working already. The contextload was not pointing to the right direction yet, and that's why it was giving me a error... 

Thanks a lot for the effort!

Comment: Dayum. Ok, well coudlnt see that coming. My concern was just, TimeStamp starts counts seconds with the beginning somewhere around 1700. Its processing its time different than DateTime. But well, nicely done. :)